# Why does Ubuntu always boot regardless of boot priority?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, architecture

I am running Ubuntu 12.10. I thought I had installed 64-bit but somehow I had installed 32-bit.

I wanted to install 64-Bit Ubuntu over the current installation with my flash drive but whenever I select my flash drive to boot, it boot into Ubuntu anyway.

My computer teacher gave me an Ubuntu 8.10 Desktop Edition DVD. Could I possibly boot from it and delete the partition so I can do a clean installation?

I looked this up for quite some time and I haven't found any answers.

Comment: How did you created Installation USB ? Did you used "Universal Usb Installer" or other means ? It looks like that this could be issue of improper USB installer.

Comment: I used Netbootin to make it. I took the .iso directly from www.Ubuntu.com.

Comment: I am guessing here. Is it possible that Boot from USB is disabled in your system BIOS ? If it is not the case then I would assume that something is definitely wrong with bootable USB. Can you try to create bootable USB again with different tool ?

Comment: Press f12 while booting for quick option. Choose your media from the list and ENTER. It will automatically boot from the drive you choose. If you had fast booting option on and the bios don't have enough time to detect the usb drive. So f12 will let the bios boot halfway and let us choose the drive to boot up. Hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a SATA, SCSI, or SAS HDD, you could unplug the all of the connected HDDs prior to boot, insert the USB drive, boot it, and then plug the drives back in.

If that doesn't work, don't use the 8.04 disc, but burn a 13.04 disc, and then try the above with a disc instead of a USB drive.

Comment: Requiring to remove SATA, SCSI and other HDD just to boot from CD/DVD is defeating the purpose of using Computer as convenience! There is something called boot device priority.